# Turn off debug or log messages in log4j.xml

Tags: java, xml, logging, log4j

I want to turn off debug or log message in log4j.xml.

My log4j.xml is :

```
<appender name="consoleAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <param name="Threshold" value="debug" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss} %5p %c{1} - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="fileAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="append" value="false" />
        <param name="file" value="./logs/learning.log" />
        <param name="Threshold" value="debug" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss} %5p %c{1} - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender" />
        <appender-ref ref="fileAppender" />
    </root>
```

My Java code :

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        log.info("info");
        log.debug("dddffff");
    }
```

If I run this program still INFO messages are also getting logged, Below is log file

```
07 Aug 2014 12:54:49  INFO MainClass - info
07 Aug 2014 12:54:49 DEBUG MainClass - dddffff
```

Now I want to turn off INFO messages.

Comment: So you want to log for ERROR messages alone . which means it shouldnt log for `logger.debug` ?

Answer (score 6):

You can turn off the log for a class or package. e.g.:

```
<!-- console -->
<appender name="STDOUT" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <param name="threshold" value="TRACE" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="conversionPattern" 
               value="%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss} %5p %c{1} - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<!-- categories -->
<category name="org.apache.commons">
    <priority value="OFF" />
</category>
<category name="org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader">
    <priority value="OFF" />
</category>

<!-- root -->
<root>
    <priority value="TRACE" />
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</root>
```

See more in [*Apache log4j 1.2 - Short introduction to log4j*](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html).

Answer (score 4):

set the logging level **Value = OFF** instead of **DEBUG**

Answer (score 2):

We should write to the log4j config file

```
<logger name="packageName.Class" additivity="false">
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="fileAppender" />
</logger>
```

I used the full qualified name of the class in the config file, which caused to the getLogger method write to the appender file only logs from the specific class. Using the name of the class only you will get in the appender file, all the logs written from other class with the same level or above.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the logging level for a package like this:

*log4j2.xml* snippet:

```
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="debug">
            <appender-ref ref="Console" />
        </Root>
        <Logger name="org.eclipse.jetty" level="info" additivity="true">
            <appender-ref ref="Console" />
        </Logger>
    </Loggers>
```

In this example, classes in the `org.eclipse.jetty` package output INFO level logging. All other classes output DEBUG level logging.

Answer (score 0):

Set the threshold value to `info`, for ex in your configuration file if you need to turn `OFF` the messages for debug to file appender,

```
<appender name="fileAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="append" value="false" />
    <param name="file" value="./logs/learning.log" />
    <param name="Threshold" value="INFO" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss} %5p %c{1} - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```

enable logging only for `info` not for debug.You can turn off logging by setting `OFF`.

[Read here for more info](http://wiki.apache.org/logging-log4j/Log4jXmlFormat) about configuring the xml file for log4j.